# Galilean boost on transverse momentum in infinite momentum frame

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

In the infinite momentum frame in $11$ dimensions, if we do a large boost along the $x^{11}$ direction, the total mass shell energy $E$ can be shown in a non relativistic approximation to be $ E - p_{11} = \frac{p_{\perp}^{2}} {2p_{11}}$ (massless case) where $p_{\perp}$ is the transverse momentum. However, I don't understand why the following Galilean transformation is correct:

$$p_{\perp} \rightarrow p_{\perp} + p_{11} v_{\perp}$$

How do we arrive at this Galilean transformation?

If we use the Lorentz boost matrix in 11 dimensions, only the momentum components in the boosted directions and the zero component should change.